# Powershell filter issue missing results

Tags: powershell

Can someone explain what is the problem with Script #1? There is a security group named **`secPBIAdmins`** but the script doesn't it find it using the filter criteria (**`?{$_.DisplayName -like '*sec*'}`**). I can see the group with user membership and when using the ObjectId.

```
Connect-AzureAD

#1) AD Group Search
Get-AzureADGroup | ?{$_.DisplayName -like '*sec*'} | select ObjectType, ObjectId, DisplayName, LastDirSyncTime | sort DisplayName | ft -auto  # , Description

#2) User (ObjectId = 'ed56cc3b-d200-4013-8aea-c208d18d7627')
Get-AzureADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName eq 'my.name@mydomain.com'" 

#3) User Groups (ObjectId = 'bdb97623-d3dc-4596-b49d-1e3392cd33df')
Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId 'ed56cc3b-d200-4013-8aea-c208d18d7627' |  select ObjectType, ObjectId, DisplayName, MailEnabled, SecurityEnabled | ft -auto 
Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId "bdb97623-d3dc-4596-b49d-1e3392cd33df" | select ObjectType, ObjectId, DisplayName, MailEnabled, SecurityEnabled | ft -auto
```

[image]

Comment: When you call `Get-AzureADGroup` by itself with no filtering does the output include the group you are looking for?

Comment: @boxdog I didn't run the command by itself but I did use ObjectId filter parameter and the group is there. `Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId "bdb97623-d3dc-4596-b49d-1e3392cd33df"`

Comment: Using the cmdlet's built in filtering might cause different behaviour internally, so I wouldn't take it as given that this group is returned normally - I'd run a quick check to be sure if it is actually being returned, then you can tell for sure if the issue is with your filter or not.

Comment: Why not `Get-AzureADGroup -filter "DisplayName -like '*sec*'"` instead of going through every group?